# Solve PDE in 2D

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Problem** How should I go about solving this PDE:

$$ \phi_x+\phi_y=x+y-3c  $$

Where $\phi = \phi(x,y)$, $c$ is a constant, and $\phi$ is specified on the circle

$$ x^2+y^2=1  $$

**My Attempt to solve it** I would like to use the method of characteristics, but then I get stuck because of the given initial condition. In fact, so far I have the characteristics equations

$$ \dot{{z}}(s)=x+y-3c $$
$$ \dot{{x}}(s)= 1 $$
$$ \dot{{y}}(s)= 1 $$

The last two are easy to solve but then I am not sure how to use the initial condition.
If you know of a different/easier method to solve this PDE, feel free to let me know, thanks!

Comment: Your "initial condition" doesn't say anything about $\phi$.  Perhaps you mean that $\phi(x,y)$ is specified on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry! I meant that $\phi$ is specified on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518094/method-of-characteristics-small-question-about-initial-conditions).

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the characteristic equations are $\dot{z} = x + y - 3 c$, $\dot{x} = 1$, $\dot{y} = 1$.  So the characteristic curves are $x = x_0 + s$, $y = y_0 + s$, i.e. $x - y = \text{constant}$.  But there's a problem with specifying the initial conditions on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$: the characteristic curves through most points either don't intersect the circle at all (so the initial condition doesn't determine $\phi$ there) or intersect it in two points (so
the initial conditions might not be consistent).

Answer (score 1):

This problem can also be solved by a substitution:
$$
   x = s+t,\;\;\; y = s-t,\;\;\; \psi(s,t)=\phi(s+t,s-t).
$$
Then
$$
   \psi_{s} = \phi_{x}+\phi_{y} = x+y-3c = 2s-3c
$$
Then there is a function $d(t)$ such that
$$
    \psi = s^{2}-3cs+d(t).
$$
The function $d$ is determined from $\psi(s,t)$, which is assumed to be known on $1=x^{2}+y^{2}=2s^{2}+2t^{2}$.