# Hyperbolic Partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following problem:
$$ u_{t}(x,t)+a(x,t)u_{x}(x,t)-f(x,t)=0\\
\ u(x,0)=0, \\$$

How to solve this equation?
Thank you.

Comment: Look for a characteristic line.

Comment: A [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518094/method-of-characteristics-small-question-about-initial-conditions).